# ng-repeat not listing different json values, instead it just displays the entire json file content in single list item

Tags: angularjs, json, ajax, angularjs-ng-repeat

ng-repeat is not listing different json values, instead it just displays the entire json file content in single list item

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/owaovm)

**html:**

```
      <div ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">

        <h2>Basic List</h2>

        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item" ng-reapeat="student">
                {{student}}
            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```

All the json file content is in here. I just need the specific data to display on each list item. 
For Example,

- Student One
- Student Two
- Student Three
- Student Four
- Student Five

[See image for issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byGn9.jpg)

**JS**

```
<script>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
//$.ajax({url: app, crossDomain:true, dataType: 'json', type: 'GET'})
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  $http.get("student.json")
 // $http.get("stud.json")
  .then(function(response) {
      $scope.student = response.data;
  });



});

</script>
```

**json**

```
[

{
    "name" : "Student One"
}, 

{
    "name" : "Student Two"
}, 

{
    "name" : "Student Three"
}, 

{
    "name" : "Student Four"
}, 

{   
    "name" : "Student Five"
}
```

]

Comment: looks like you didn't read the documentation of angular js https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 0):

Your `ng-repeat` should be look like, to be more on that, you are missing the proper syntax and its **`ng-repeat`** not **`ng-reapeat`**

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="stu in student" >
     {{stu.name}}
 </li>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.student = 
[
  {
    "name": "Student One"
  },
  {
    "name": "Student Two"
  },
  {
    "name": "Student Three"
  },
  {
    "name": "Student Four"
  },
  {
    "name": "Student Five"
  }
];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
</head>
<body >
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="myCtrl" > 
<div class="container">
<h2>Basic List</h2>
 <ul class="list-group">
  <li    ng-repeat="stu in student"  >
    {{stu.name}}
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

I fixed the syntax of the parameter in ng-repeat attribute.

So instead of the previous :

```
<ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item" ng-reapeat="student">
                {{student}}
            </li>
```

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd5rQ.jpg)

it should be like this :

```
 <ul class="list-group" >
  <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="student in student" >
    {{student.name}}
</li>
```

Result:
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QFqk.jpg)